# How to create a new record in a dstore using dmodel

Tags: dojo, dstore

I assign a model to a store then call

```
var model = Store.create({id:0,firstName:"john",lastName:"smith",department:"sales"});
model.save();
```

This sends a PUT request. Shouldn't it send a POST? I tried not including the id field but then it throws a validation error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is working var model = Store.create({firstName: "john", lastName: "smith", department: "sales"});     Store.add(model);

Comment: This also works  var model = new MyModel({firstName: "john", lastName: "smith", department: "sales"});    Store.add(model);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can not send any id and have it POST. The best way to do this then is either

```
var model = Store.create({firstName: "john", lastName: "smith", department: "sales"}); 
Store.add(model);
```

or

```
var model = new MyModel({firstName: "john", lastName: "smith", department: "sales"}); 
Store.add(model);
```